# Disable submit button until form value changes and reverts in Angular

Tags: angular

The submit button should be disabled until one value changes at least. I have found the solution:

`<button [disabled]="!form.dirty">Submit</button>`

But, the problem is that if the user deletes the changes and uses the existing values, it won't make the button disable again. For example, in the `app.component.html` file:

```
<form [formGroup]="createForm">
  <label for="email">formText</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" formControlName="formText" />
  <br />
  <label>List</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" formControlName="list" />
</form>
<button [disabled]="createForm.invalid || !createForm.dirty">Submit</button>
<h3>{{ someError }}</h3>
```

and in the `app.component.ts` file:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      formText: ['hello', Validators.required],
      list: [10, Validators.required],
    });
  }
}
```

These generate this output:

[image]

If the user changes the value for example 11 in the second input; the disabled state has been removed as expected.

[image]

But, if the user reverts the changes (so the input value is 10 again), I want to add the disabled state in the button again. How to do that?

[Code Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-reactive-form-disabled-button-on-change-2g19zd?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: dirty only signals that the form has not been touched yet. For your case you have to do the logic yourself. Store all default values in an object and whenever all input fields have the same value as the default state you disable the button.

Comment: I am a bit of new in Angular. At which lifecycle method, I need to write my custom logic (checking the input values with the default object)?

Comment: no lifecycle method. you do this check whenever the input value changes. because that's when you want to enable / disable the button.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```js
export class MyComponent {
  originalValue = '';
  inputValue = '';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.originalValue = this.inputValue;
  }

  isButtonDisabled() {
    return this.inputValue !== this.originalValue;
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input [(ngModel)]="inputValue">
  <button [disabled]="isButtonDisabled()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
interface FormModel {                   // (1)
    formText: string;
    list: number;
}


private originalFormValue: FormModel;   // (2)
form?: FormGroup<FormModel>;

submitDisabled$: Observable<boolean>;   // (3)



constructor() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        formText: ['hello', Validators.required],
        list: [10, Validators.required]
    }); 
    
    this.originalFormValue = this.form.value;   // (4)

    this.submitDisabled$ = this.form.valueChanges.pipe(        // (5)
        map(value => this.objectsAreEquals(value, this.originalFormValue) || this.form.inalid)
    );
}


private objectsAreEquals(model1: FormModel, model2: FormModel): boolean {
   ... do the comparison here (you could use a library like lodash, e.g. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lodash-_-isequal-method/)
}
```

and in the template:

```
...
<button [disabled]="submitDisabled$ | async">Submit</button>
...
```

(1) the datamodel for the form (since angular 14 forms are typed)
(2) contains the original form-value to compare with
(3) an observable, which emits boolean-values (true, if the submit-button should ebe disabled)
(4) save the original value (such that you can compare it, when the form-value changes)
(5) this is the tricky part for beginners:

- form.valueChanges returns an Observable, which emits a new value each time any of the form-fields changes value. It contains the values of all fields (to be precise: the value of all enabled form-fields)
- using the map-operator you convert this FormModel into a boolean by comparing it with the original value and checking the invalid-flag of the form)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I  have solved it similarly to your logic. I made it simpler such as avoiding the use of Observable. So, instead of a generic solution, my solution was component specific. I did that as I am new to angular. But I will try to use your solution later. Thanks again